# How to split one control end of bezier curve

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, edit-mode

I am making a path using bezier curve and having an object which follows the path using steering actuator. My problem is having a path which resembles the English letter "Y", for that I need to split one of the control end of the curve. How can I do that?

Also, if the path has the shape of "P", how can I join one control end of the bezier curve to an intermediary control point?

I am not an expert in Blender. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create such shapes only by combining 2 or multiple curves, because

> Each new segment is added to one end of the curve. A new segment will
>   only be added if a single vertex, or handle, at one end of the curve
>   is selected.

*[wiki page](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html?highlight=curve#extending-curves)*

The same may be applied to creating 'P' shape, thus joining 2 curve segments - it'll raise an error "Cannot make segment". You can duplicate that curve segment and place it atop of existing one, but still it'd be 2 different curves (example below).

As another way you may want to use simple mesh with all vertices deleted except for one. You then extrude shape needed either with <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd>:

[image: split-curve_1]

After adding mirror modifier you'll get that 'Y' shape. If you convert now this mesh into curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you'll see that it actually consists of 2 curves:

[image: split-curve_2]

It's just the same what you would get if extruding this shape with curves manually.