# Attach vertex to a circle with a line?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, vertices

I have a basic circle with lets say 20 vertices.
I then do a ctrl+right click to place a vertex somewhere outside the circle.
I then select the vertex outside the circle, hold shift, select a vertex on the circle and hit f.
And nothing happens.
I can ctrl+right click around and shift select and f lines all day. But can't seem to get the vertex to join the circle with a line.

Comment: pls consider adding images for clarity.

Comment: Are you doing it in edit mode so they are one shape?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to model and animate a bifurcated path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135053/how-to-model-and-animate-a-bifurcated-path) and [creating a divided highway using curves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93737/creating-divided-highway-using-nurbs-curves/93756#93756) and [Is it possible to extrude a curve in two directions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/is-it-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-in-two-directions) and [split one control end of a bezier curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33535)

Comment: I figured out something else that was probably simple for most seasoned users. I needed to select everything and ctrl+j to make it all one object. I was then able to connect whatever i needed to the circle- and then make faces

Answer (score 5):

In curves, the vertices cannot be linked to more than two segments, curves cannot be forked or bifurcated.

[image]

To create such shape you would need to add a new disconnected curve segment and place it on top of an existing one.

[image]

Comment: thank you susu, thats what i needed to see